# Get parent divs to match height and width of contents

Tags: css, grid

The parent #Connect has two rows #unit1 & #unit2. Each row has two columns .col1 & .col2. I'm having two issues:

1. #Connect only gets as falls as #unit1 -- so I cannot see the blue background.I would like #Connect to be as wide as the browser but as tall as it's contents.
2. I want #unit1 & #unit2 have a background that is as wide as #Connect and as tall as .col2. Currently, I cannot see any background.

Below is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="colReflow.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            #connect .col1{
                float: left; width: 240px; background-color: #ffc0cb;
            }
            #connect .col2{
                background-color: yellow; margin-left: 248px;
            }
            #connect .offCont{
                position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; float: left;
                width: 210px;height:256px;
                color: #000000;
                font-family: "TrumpGothicEastBold",Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
                background: #9acd32;
            }
            #connect .section{
                /*I want the background to be as 100% width of Connect and the height of the contents of col2*/
                background: #ff69b4;clear: both; width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="connect">

            <div id="unit1" class="section">
                <div class="col1">This column is used solely to hold this area.</div>

                <div class="col2">
                    <div class="offCont">drgdrg</div>
                    <div class="offCont">drgdrg</div>
                    <div class="offCont">drgdrg</div>
                    <div class="offCont">drgdrg</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="unit2" class="section">
                <div class="col1">This column is used solely to hold this area.</div>

                <div class="col2">
                    <div class="offCont">I want this section or unit 2 to be as tall as the contents of col2</div>
                    <div class="offCont">drgdrg</div>
                    <div class="offCont">drgdrg</div>
                    <div class="offCont">drgdrg</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answering my own here. Put overflow: hidden; on both #connect and the .section class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put

```
overflow: hidden;
```

On #connect and .section